# Default user registry (NTUSER.DAT) not used anymore?

Tags: registry, windows-11

I'm trying to create an image - where newly logged in users get settings in their registry pushed as Windows 11 creates their new profile.

For this, I've loaded the C:\USERS\Default\NTUSER.DAT hive into my registry (HKLM\TEMP) and made several changes to many of the keys..

However, it looks like this profile NTUSER.DAT is not being used anymore.. new users that log in do not get any of the changes.. and I do not see any of these changes either in the HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT  (while reloading Default\NTUSER.DAT does reflect these)

Is there another file I should load to make the changes in ?